# list.insert(position, value) grows list indefinitely

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

If I run the following code:

```
data = list()
length = 10

for i in range(1000):
    point = i % length
    data.insert(point, i)

len(data)
```

The output is: 1000

I was expecting the length to be 10 as I am restricting point to be in range 0-9.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `list.insert` doesn't do *replacement* of the item at the specified index; it *inserts* the new item, and pushes everything after it "down" one slot.

Comment: `insert` *inserts* a new item; `data[i] =` *replaces*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert adds elements in a new position, to overwrite old ones try this instead:

```
length = 10
data = [None] * length

for i in range(1000):
    point = i % length
    data[point] = i

len(data)
=> 10
```

Although it's not clear why you want to loop 1000 times when only the last 10 values are needed... Wouldn't it better to use `range(990, 1000)`?

Comment: Your example is going to have an `IndexError` after 10 loops; you indexed to `i` (unreduced), not `point` (`i` reduced to within the appropriate range).